# Deserializing a Spark Dstream

Tags: java, complex-event-processing, spark-streaming, drools-fusion

I am trying to apply Drools Engine (Drools Fusion) over streaming data using Spark Streaming.

But I am unable to deserialize a variable of type JavaDStreamto fire rules over it.

It is showing comparision error between JavaDstream and Interger. Please suggest how to resolve this. Below is the Code

Main class

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("Spark Streaming");

    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(10000));

    JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = jssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 8089);

    class splitFunc implements Function<String, Long> {
        public Long call(String x) { return Long.parseLong(x); }
        }


     JavaDStream<Long>  in_amount = lines.map(new splitFunc());

     insertEvent(entryPointStoreOne,new Sale(),in_amount);
```

Sale.java - FACTS

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;

public class Sale {

private JavaDStream<Long> amount;

public Sale (){ }

public void setAmount(JavaDStream<Long> amount)
{
    this.amount=amount;
}

public JavaDStream<Long> getAmount()
{
    return amount;
}
```

}

Drools Rules File

```
declare Sale
@role(event)
end


 rule "Store One - Has Passed its Sales Record"
 when
    $amount : Sale( amount > 1000 ) - FAILING HERE 
    from entry-point StoreOne      
  then
    System.out.println("Store One has passed its Sales Records");
  end
```